# Using BeautifulSoup Library with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm following a tutorial on creating a map using Python and the Beautiful Soup library.

I have downloaded beautiful soup and the folder is called "beautifulsoup4-4.1.3". The contents of this folder are in the attached image.

During the tutorial I am given the following code to use to import my data and beautiful soup:

```
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Trouble is that there is no file called "beautiful soup" within the beautiful soup folder. I have also attached the error message I receive in the terminal.

How should I import beautiful soup when there is no file with that name? I tried simply changing the folders name to "beautiful soup". I did not expect that to work and I was right - it did not.

Any advice on how to proceed welcome?

[image]

[image: beautiful soup directory]

Comment: Open terminal, start python and type this: `help('modules')`.  Do you see anything related to `BeautifulSoup` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either move the `bs4` folder in the same directory as your script, or install the module via `easy_install` or `pip`. Then you can import it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 5):

You installed the BeautifulSoup library version 4, which has been renamed:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

If you want the old name and matching API, you need to install BeautifulSoup 3 instead:

```
easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

Note that since your tutorial is using `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` it may not entirely work with the updated API of BeautifulSoup version 4. If you run into problems, take a look at the [porting to BS4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4) section of the BeautifulSoup documentation to 'translate' BS 3 code to the 4 API.

Answer (score 2):

To use BeautifulSoup 4, you need to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

It seems to me like you are reading the wrong manual.