# Can someone help me to scrape html using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have downloaded Beautifulsoup and want to import it in my python program. I have typed my python program as below:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print 'TAG:',tag
    print 'URL:',tag.get('href', None)
    print 'Contents:',tag.contents[0]
    print 'Attrs:',tag.attrs
```

Now i have saved it in a different folder.
When i try running the program, i get the following error.

[image: error message]

So, what could be the reason for this and how can I make it work?
Thanks in advance !
I'm using Python 2.7.13 and will **import** work in it?
i tried importing **bs4** and it gave **import is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Comment: Is the Python path saved properly?

Comment: Try this : `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using BeautifulSoup Library with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000180/using-beautifulsoup-library-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a problem with the pythonpath.

Check you had made the correct setup for this library: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

`bs4` is a library, you should import it.

Document: [Quick Start](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.13 and will _import_ work in it? i tried importing **bs4** and it gave **import is not recognized as an internal or external command**